# Connect services within a single docker

Tags: docker, network-programming

I have a simple Flask app using uwsgi and nginx.
I use supervisord to launch them.
The Flask app works fine but when I try to use another service I setup in this docker in the Flask app, it hangs. I think it's a network issue.

Normally when I run this Flask app on my local environment the code works.
This is the line where problem occurs.

```
bc = BertClient()
```

This is using a default ip address of 'localhost'. It connects to a BertServer set up in the same container. The Server looks fine.

I'm wondering should I change localhost to something else since I'm using docker but not my local environment?

Comment: Generally `localhost` in Docker means "this container".  When you say "a single Docker" do you mean running on the same Docker daemon, or the same Docker network, or in the same Docker Compose file, or are you attempting to run multiple programs in the same Docker container?

Comment: Yes, I mean in the same Docker container.